# cant compare 2 always shows that the numbers are not the same

Tags: python

I have more code but this one is responsible for checking the answer to the question

````
oso = random.randint(1,500)
oso2 = random.randint(1,500)
pls = oso ++ oso2
plos = pls
print(oso2 , "+" , oso)
opo = input("d")
ops = opo
if pls == opo:
    print("nice")


else: print(unlucky)```
````

Comment: what is `unlucky`?

Comment: One value is an integer and the other a string.

Comment: @Miles07 word I just forgot to put ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
pls = oso ++ oso2
```

You should remove the double plus sign

With `opo = input("d")` you're taking in input a string, because input returns a string: 
Your code doesn't work because u are comparing a string to an integer, so the equality condition is never reached.
Replace your input with:

```
opo = int(input("d"))
```